# Logarithmic and power corrections to BH formula

Tags: black-holes, entropy, qft-in-curved-spacetime, black-hole-thermodynamics

What reasons (if any) beyond the information loss paradox is why we believe that BH entropy formula:
$$S=\dfrac{A}{4L_p^2}$$
recieves power or log-corrections, like
$$S_c=S_{BH}+\sum_{n\neq 0}c_n\dfrac{A^n}{(4L_p^2)^n}+c_0\log(A/4L_p^2)~?$$

Comment: quark-gluon plasma perhaps?

Comment: Logarithmic corrections to BH entropy are due to small
statistical fluctuations around equilibrium, cf. e.g. [arXiv:hep-th/0111001](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0111001).

Comment: 1. I find your question hard to parse - two display-style formulae in a sentence break the reading flow, consider being a bit more verbose. 2. Please define variables used - even though one could guess it, it is much better to be explicit about what e.g. $c_0,A,L_p$ are. 3. Consider giving at least one reference for the second formula, since it is currently unclear where it comes from at all.